# Help me simplify this expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am unable to simplify this expression, help me in this regard, thanks in advance.
I tried this : Normal//ToRadicals//FullSimplify

```
5 - RootSum[
  5 + 6 #1^2 + 6 #1^3 &, (
   5 Log[1 - #1] - 5 Log[1 - #1] #1 + 11 Log[1 - #1] #1^2)/(
   2 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
 RootSum[5 + 6 #1^2 + 6 #1^3 &, (
   5 Log[-#1] - 5 Log[-#1] #1 + 11 Log[-#1] #1^2)/(2 #1 + 3 #1^2) &]
```

Comment: Did you try `N`?

Comment: I need a closed-form expression, not a numerical value.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Re[ToRadicals[exp]], 
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify `  Imaginary part proofs to be zero this way.

Comment: This is helpful, I got the result, thank you!

Comment: @Akku14 Why do not you place your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
ComplexExpand[Re[ToRadicals[expr]],TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify
```

Imaginary part proves to be zero this way.